# Set timeout for g++ build and run for Sublime Text?

Tags: c++, g++, sublimetext3, clang++

I am using g++ on Sublime Text 3 on ubuntu, for building and running my c++ programs. The build system currently looks like this:

```
{
"cmd" : ["g++ -std=c++14 -Wall $file_name -o $file_base_name && timeout 4s ./$file_base_name<input.txt>output.txt"], 
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell": true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path",
}
```

As you can see in the first line, the timeout is set to 4 seconds, but if I accidentally run an infinite loop, the timeout does not work and Sublime just hangs up. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's my cpp build system in sublime text. Since it is mac, I have installed coreutils and used the mac flavoured `gtimeout` command. My setup will terminate the program after 7 seconds.

```
{
"cmd": ["g++ -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name} -lm -std=c++17 $file && gtimeout 7 ${file_path}/${file_base_name} && rm ${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.cpp, source.c++",
// "path": "C:/cygwin64/bin",
"shell": true,
"variants": [
    {
        "name": "Build",
        "cmd": ["g++ -o ${file_path}/${file_base_name} -lm -std=c++17 $file && rm ${file_path}/${file_base_name}"]
    }
]
```

}